# Using select with map within { } appending blank array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to use `select` in a loop to append results matching from another `map` loop.

The following select piece of code comes up with a blank array:

```
vendor_products = VendorProduct.where(vendor_id: vendor_order.vendor_id)
vendor_order.order.line_items.select do |li|
  li.shop_product.product == vendor_products.map {|vp| vp.product }
end
```

Even in the console it's blank with `[]`

When i do:

```
vendor_order.order.line_items.select { |li| li.shop_product.product }
```

On its own, it appends results. (using `each`, `map`, etc.)

When I do:

```
vendor_products.map {|vp| vp.product }
```

On it's own, it appends results as well.

Doing:

```
vendor_order.order.line_items.select { |li| li.shop_product.product_id == 1 }}
```

Works as well and shows results.

I've tried using `product_id` over `product` but still comes up blank.  Although, I need the entire `Product` anyway

---

When both loops are on it's own, the results match up, the `Product` matching, so the select should be coming up with the matching results, but somehow isn't.  Is using map within the `{}` not applicable?

---

Is there something wrong with my code and how can i get the results?

My goal is to do something like this:

```
def foo
    vendor_products = VendorProduct.where(vendor_id: self.vendor_id)
    product = self.order.line_items.select { |li| li.shop_product.product == vendor_products.map {|vp| vp.product }}
    return "#{product.title, product.color}"
end
```

And use this for CSV output.

Comment: Is `li.shop_product.product` a single product? Then `i.shop_product.product == vendor_products.map {|vp| vp.product }` will never be true since `.map` is returning an array of products. So your `select` will select nothing. Maybe you're misunderstanding how `.select` works, which is to return all of the elements that make the block return truthy.

Comment: I assume select returns matching results, ones that are true. `[1,2,3].select { |s| s == 4}` will return `[4]`...Or am I seeing something wrong here

Comment: In your example, it will return an empty array, as no element in the object is equals to "4", but, select returns all elements where the condition in the block is evaluated to true, so, it can be 0, 1 or more. In your case you should be using `find` which applies the same logic that select, but returns just the first element after that

Comment: Oops I meant 3 instead of 4....

Comment: `.select` returns the list of items for which the block returns true, as I mentioned in my first comment. Your block expression is always false. See the online docs for `.select`.

Comment: why does `[1,2,3].select { |s| s == 3}` return `["3"]` but if i were to map to get 3, it would be blank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try just using SQL, in the Active Record way:

```
product = VendorProduct.where(vendor_id: vendor_id,
                              product_id: order.line_items.shop_product.id)
"#{product.title, product.color}"
```

Comment: Yeah you a beast

Comment: Maybe you can check your relationships, so you could be able to get the product right from the vendor. Something easier, as here you need to get the product id from a long chain of methods.